# "when" conditions for platformio and Arduino extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I use both the PlatformIO and the Arduino plugins for Visual Studio Code.

I want to use the same keybindings to mean 'build' and 'upload' on both.

What do I put in the "when" clause in the keybindings to differentiate between the two?

Is there a `"when": "inArduinoMode"` and `"when": "inPlatformIOMode"`?

I have checked [the official Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) but as far as I can tell it only covers built-in functionality and makes no mention of special behaviour for contexts added by extensions.